# I'm facing some errors when I try to setup a wireless mesh network using ns3.38 on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: compiling

I'm using Ubuntu version 22.04, and trying to run a script using ns-3 3.38 that set ups a mesh wireless network. However I get errors after running it.

> error: 'Default' is not a member of 'ns3: YansiWifiHelper'

> error: 'WIFI_PHY_STANDARD_80211N_5GHZ' was not declared in this scope

I will provide the script without the header files. I have two errors, and I will mark the lines.

```
using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE("SimpleMeshNetwork");

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    LogComponentEnable("SimpleMeshNetwork", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

    NodeContainer nodes;
    nodes.Create(4);

    MobilityHelper mobility;
    mobility.SetPositionAllocator("ns3::GridPositionAllocator",
                                  "MinX", DoubleValue(0.0),
                                  "MinY", DoubleValue(0.0),
                                  "DeltaX", DoubleValue(100.0),
                                  "DeltaY", DoubleValue(100.0),
                                  "GridWidth", UintegerValue(2),
                                  "LayoutType", StringValue("RowFirst"));
    mobility.SetMobilityModel("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
    mobility.Install(nodes);

    WifiHelper wifi;
    wifi.SetStandard(WIFI_PHY_STANDARD_80211s);
    wifi.SetRemoteStationManager("ns3::ConstantRateWifiManager",
                                 "DataMode", StringValue("OfdmRate6Mbps"));

    YansWifiPhyHelper wifiPhy = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default();
    wifiPhy.Set("ChannelNumber", UintegerValue(7));

    YansWifiChannelHelper wifiChannel = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default();
    wifiPhy.SetChannel(wifiChannel.Create());

    MeshHelper mesh = MeshHelper::Default();
    mesh.SetStackInstaller("ns3::Dot11sStack");
    mesh.SetSpreadInterfaceChannels(MeshHelper::SPREAD_CHANNELS);
    mesh.SetMacType("RandomStart", TimeValue(Seconds(0.1)));

    NetDeviceContainer meshDevices = mesh.Install(wifiPhy, nodes);

    InternetStackHelper internet;
    internet.Install(nodes);

    Ipv4AddressHelper address;
    address.SetBase("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfaces = address.Assign(meshDevices);

    Simulator::Stop(Seconds(10.0));

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nodes.GetN(); ++i) {
        Ptr<Node> node = nodes.Get(i);
        Ptr<Ipv4> ipv4 = node->GetObject<Ipv4>();
        Ipv4InterfaceAddress iaddr = ipv4->GetAddress(1, 0);
        Ipv4Address addr = iaddr.GetLocal();
        NS_LOG_INFO("Node " << i << " has IP address " << addr);
    }

    Simulator::Run();
    Simulator::Destroy();

    return 0;
} 



How to solve such errors?
```

Comment: No Ubunto 22.04 LTS

Comment: Can you help me or no? In solving the errors.

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu 22.04 provides libs3-dev version 3.35, so presumably you installed 3.38 by some other means. At least in 3.35, the standards (in wifi-standards.h) use *lower case* a/b/g/n suffixes ex. `WIFI_PHY_STANDARD_80211n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
wifi.SetStandard(ns3::WIFI_STANDARD_80211n);
```

Try to use this line instead in `n3.38` you need to write without specifying the frequency band.